# ImageMagick Montage With Exiftool output as -label

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, exiftool

I am working on creating contact sheets with Image Magick's montage command. I would like to include particular meta data as the `-label` for the contact sheet images. I am pulling the data using exiftool:

```
$creator = C:\exiftool.exe "-Creator" $image
```

and creating the montage like so:

```
montage -verbose -label %t_$creator -pointsize 20 -background '#FFFFFF' -tile '5x40' -fill 'black' -define jpeg:size=600x780 -geometry 600x780+40+150 -quality 90  -auto-orient $dailyImages.FullName E:\Contact_Sheet.jpg
```

However, I run into an issue of the `-label` containing the creator for ALL the files in the directory `$dailyImages` instead of the creator for each respective file.

Is anyone able to use the exiftool command to pull a single file's 'creator' and pipe it into the montage command so the respective image on the contact sheet as `$filename_$creator`. (In case you are unfamiliar, the `%t` in `-label %t_$creator` is built in to Image Magick to provide the filename as the `-label`)

Comment: If you want this question answered, you will have to post specific output generated by the programs. Those programs are not PowerShell and you cannot expect someone to have them. I am assuming $Creator is an array of strings so you'll probably have to do some type of foreach loop.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Creator tag. I do not see it at https://sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/EXIF.html and ImageMagick has no Creator access for its EXIF tags at http://www.imagemagick.org/script/escape.php. Perhaps you can run the full list of exif data using exiftool and present it here to show that the Creator tag exists. Perhaps it is a custom tag?

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough information, -Creator is, as @StarGeek mentioned, a XMP Metadata field. Our files currently have a username in this field. I am using exiftool to extract that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what I said above, if you want some EXIF data that ImageMagick supports, then you can do for example:

```
montage -label "%t %[EXIF:make]" input.jpg output.jpg
```

I have tested that and it works on an image I have.

This also works for me on ImageMagick 6.9.9.23 Q16 Mac OSX.

```
make=`convert input.jpg -format "%[EXIF:make]" info:`
montage -label "%t $make" input.jpg output.jpg
```

This also works for me:

```
make=`exiftool -make input.jpg | sed 's/ *//g' | cut -d: -f2`
montage -label "%t $make" input.jpg output.jpg
```

So everything seems to point to the lack of a Creator field in EXIF data.

Comment: `Creator` is an XMP metadata field.  The EXIF equivalent would be `Artist`.